# How can I access Jenkins build artifacts from the groovy Postbuild plugin?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there a way to read a build artifact file using the Groovy postbuild plugin?

**Some context:**
I have written some testng tests that are run by maven in Jenkins.  Jenkins runs the tests, gives me the test results, etc.  However, I have been asked to also store the results in HP's Application Lifeycycle Management (ALM).  A coworker provided me with a post-build groovy script that can interface with ALM and store the test results.  I have to pass these parameters to that script:

- jobname
- pass/fail status
- test start time

My idea was to store testng-results.xml as an artifact and parse out the results with xmlslurper, but I don't know how to read the artifact from the groovy plugin.  From the [groovy postbuild plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) I have gathered that it might also be possible to read the test results directly from the manager.build variable, but I don't have a lot of experience with Jenkins or this plugin and so far I have been unsuccessful.

I'm also open to other approaches as well.  The groovy script is running on the Jenkins server, not on the slave node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case this is useful for anyone in the future, the solution that I went with was to find the artifact that I was looking for in `manager.build.getArtifacts()` and join that path with `manager.build.getArtifactsDir()`